# Scrapy response.xpath not returning anything for a query

Tags: shell, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am using the scrapy shell to extract some text data. Here are the commands i gave in the scrapy shell:

```
>>> scrapy shell "http://jobs.parklandcareers.com/dallas/nursing/jobid6541851-nurse-resident-cardiopulmonary-icu-feb2015-nurse-residency-requires-contract-jobs"

>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[1]/text()')
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[1]/text()' data=u'Dallas, TX'>]
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[2]/p/text()[2]')
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[2]/p/text()[2]' data=u'Responsible for attending assigned nursi'>]
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[2]/p/text()[preceding-sibling::*="Education"][following-sibling::*="Certification"]')
[]
```

The third command is not returning any data. I was trying to extract data between 2 keywords in the command. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[2]/p/text()` would return you a list of text nodes. You can filter the relevant nodes in Python. Here's how you can get the text between *"Education/Experience:"* and *"Certification/Registration/Licensure:"* text paragraphs:

```
>>> result = response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[2]/p/text()').extract()
>>> start = result.index('Education/Experience:')
>>> end = result.index('Certification/Registration/Licensure:')
>>> print ''.join(result[start+1:end])
- Must be a graduate from an accredited school of Nursing.
```

UPD (regarding an additional question in comments):

```
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[3]/text()').re('Job ID: (\d+)')
[u'143112']
```

Comment: i have one more small query in this question. I have tried something like this:     >>> jid=response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[3]/text()').extract()   .... and i tried extracting only the number and remove the "Job ID:"...but the start does not work the same way..the index was not in the list

Comment: @crozzfire sure, this is a good use case for [`.re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions), please see the update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
substring-before(
  substring-after('//*[@id="jobDesc"]/span[2]/p/text()', 'Education'), 'Certification')
```

Note: I couldn't test it.

The idea is that you cannot use `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` because you look in the same text node. You have to extract the text part that you want using `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`

By combining those two functions, you select what is in between.